# Nativescript Mapbox screen capture

Tags: javascript, java, android, nativescript, mapbox-android

My app offers a button to take a screenshot of the current page, which includes a Mapbox map (handled by the nativescript-mapbox plugin). Everything works fine on iOS but on Android, the map is not rendering.

I was pointed from the mapbox team to this example, which addresses their issue with the "regular" Android Graphics Canvas, providing a solution using the Mapbox Snapshot API: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/imagegenerator/SnapshotActivity.java#L52

As I am not a Java developer (I barely can handle the {NS} part :) ), I don't know how to convert the code to my pure Javascript {NS} code.

This is what I have now:

```
var v = view;
var bmp = android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()+50, android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
v.android.draw(new android.graphics.Canvas(bmp));
var source = new imageSource.ImageSource();
source.setNativeSource(bmp);

//saves image into Documents folder
var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents().path;
var fileName = "Test.png"
var path = fs.path.join(folder, fileName);
var saved = source.saveToFile(path, "png");
```

Any ideas on how to convert/use their code to capture my entire view, including the map?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would help as that code will take a snapshot of the map, not your entire page..

Comment: Thanks for jumping in @EddyVerbruggen. So, no luck to me? No way to capture a screen with a mapbox element on Android?